# How to add paginate function to join and groupBy query?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to achieve pagination after joining and grouping the query.

I have already tried other ideas but can't make pagination object appear, instead it will only show as a normal collection.

`$this->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')->get()->groupBy('title');`

I tried `$this->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')->get()->groupBy('title')->paginate(15);` but it doesn't work. Where should i add paginate() function or do i need to do something other than that? Please let me know if i should explain more.

Comment: I figured it out that in order to get the pagination working, I just had to set ```'strict' => false```, in database.php. This made the pagination work but now the problem is that the given results are not grouped. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have found so far, there seems to be an issue in pagination with `groupBy()` in Laravel. So, in order to achieve this, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `get()` method, the `paginate()` method won't work anymore. So just remove the `get()` method like this : `$this->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')->groupBy('title')->paginate(15);`

Comment: This would not work. Please check the above remarks i made.

Comment: You can try this `$this->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')->groupBy('products.title')->paginate(15);`

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
$this->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')->groupBy('title')->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Already tried this and this would cause ```Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mydb.stocks.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `stocks` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `stocks`.`product_id` group by `title` limit 5 offset 0)``` error to occur.

Comment: Yes it will throw error because. previously you have applied groupby in collections but this answer will apply groupby in query builder

Comment: @Manojkiran.A , the error produced above IS caused by using the given code i.e. ```$this->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')->groupBy('title')->paginate(15);```   Even after removing the `get()` method.